# 2055:...... system error: 1 [SSL: NO_CIPHERS_AVAILABLE] no ciphers available (_ssl.c:997)

Tags: python, mysql

```
from mysql.connector import connect,Error
try:
    with connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='455476') as db:
        mycursor=db.cursor()

        mycursor.execute('SHOW DATABASE')
        for database in mycursor:
            print(database)

except Error as error:
    print(error)
```

answer python:

> 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system error: 1 [SSL: NO_CIPHERS_AVAILABLE] no ciphers available (_ssl.c:997)

Comment: Does the MySQl server require SSL certificates for connection?